# Jacobians and ranks of a curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

I would like to know the following:

How to find Jacobian and rank of an hyper elliptic curve like $x^5-x= y^2-y$?

High regards

Rosy

Comment: You can use [*sage*](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/plane_curves/sage/schemes/hyperelliptic_curves/jacobian_generic.html), and read [Poonen](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ants2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I used Magma to compute the rank and torsion subgroup of the jacobian, as follows:

```
P<x>:=PolynomialRing(Rationals());
C:=HyperellipticCurve(x^5-x,-1);
J:=Jacobian(C);
RankBounds(J);
C:=HyperellipticCurve(4*(x^5-x-1/4),0);
TorsionSubgroup(Jacobian(C));
```

For the torsion, Magma requires the curve to be of the form $y^2=f(x)$, so I changed variables and wrote the curve as $y^2=4x^5-4x-1$. The answer is $J\cong \mathbb{Z}^3$.

If you want to do this by hand, then I recommend [the linked article by Michael Stoll](http://journals.impan.pl/cgi-bin/doi?aa98-3-4).

Comment: Lozano-Robledo! How to find genus of my curve?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelliptic_curve

Comment: Lozano-Robledo! I still confused to find genus of my curve. Please explain and find genus of my curve which is given in my post.